# hasOwnProperty returns false But The object that seems to have properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

My JSON.stringify return empty object notation "{}" for an object that seems to have properties?

And hasOwnProperty returns false  But The object that seems to have properties?

This is my properties

[image]:-

My JSON.stringify code:-

```
 const locals =JSON.stringify(action.data.displayNameLocalization);
 console.log( locals);
```

If my object have properties,hasOwnProperty() return false.

```
const test=action.data.displayNameLocalization;
console.log(test);
console.log(test.hasOwnProperty());
```

[image]

Result:-

[image]

I have no idea what is happening...? Anyone can help men with this..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69955330 Still need a MCVE - likely an asynchronous issue

Comment: Can you explain little but more..?

Comment: Did you look at the link in the comments in your prior question?

Comment: Yes...But That is not  the reason

Comment: It most likely is - but again, there's no MCVE, so it's hard to say since there isn't enough detail. Please edit closed questions to make them not off-topic instead of re-posting them

Comment: `test.hasOwnProperty()` is equivalent to `test.hasOwnProperty("undefined")`. Of course it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it) so you should pass a property name when using this function.

Note, that you can use the new `Object.hasOwn()` static method which returns true or false indicating if the specified object has the indicated property as its own property (yet it is still not supported by all browsers)

```js
const test = {ch : 'China', fr: 'Franch'};
console.log(test.hasOwnProperty('ch')); // checking if the property `ch` is an own property
console.log(test.hasOwnProperty()); // checking for undefined..

console.log(Object.hasOwn(test, 'ch')); // using the new Object.hasOwn method
```

More about `hasOwnProperty` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty